# Error while querying SQL Server databases using WMI in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, wmi

I have this WMI query that is generated by a tool. I have SQL server 2008 (instance MSSQLServer2008) installed in Windows 7 machine. I am using the following query in PowerShell and I get "Invalid class" error:

```
gwmi -Query "SELECT Name FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLMSSQLSERVER2008_MSSQLMSSQLSERVER2008Databases"
```

The error is:

> gwmi : Invalid class
>   "Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLMSSQLSERVER2008_MSSQLMSSQLSERVER2008Databases" At line:1 char:1
>   + gwmi -Query "SELECT Name FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLMSSQLSERVE ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

As mentioned the query is generated through a tool so I cannot change it to another command. I want to know if the query is wrong and how to fix it.

Edit 1:
This is the list of all classes:

PS C:\Users\rahman> Get-WMIObject –List –namespace "root" –class "*SQL*" -Recurse | select path

### Path

\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\root\CIMV2:Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETDataProviderforSqlServer_NETDataPr
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\root\CIMV2:Win32_PerfRawData_NETDataProviderforSqlServer_NETDataProvider
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:MSSQLSERVER2008Trace
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent160
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent160_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent201
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent201_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent150
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent150_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent107
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent107_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent144
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent144_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent108
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent108_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent142
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent142_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent167
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent167_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent24
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent24_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent87
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent87_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent97
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent97_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent214
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent214_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent74
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent74_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent114
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent114_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent27
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent27_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent85
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent85_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent135
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent135_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent53
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent53_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent22
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent22_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent131
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent131_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent89
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent89_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent76
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent76_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent94
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent94_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent67
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent67_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent200
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent200_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent83
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent83_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent77
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent77_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent45
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent45_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent194
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent194_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent190
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent190_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent146
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent146_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent216
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent216_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent90
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent90_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent132
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent132_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent159
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent159_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent34
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent34_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent134
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent134_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent126
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent126_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent133
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent133_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent51
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent51_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent72
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent72_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent176
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent176_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent117
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent117_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent78
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent78_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent59
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent59_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent75
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent75_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent195
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent195_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent156
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent156_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent115
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent115_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent61
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent61_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent185
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent185_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent103
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent103_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent186
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent186_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent79
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent79_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent104
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent104_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent86
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent86_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent125
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent125_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent213
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent213_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent154
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent154_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent202
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent202_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent80
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent80_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent112
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent112_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent172
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent172_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent121
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent121_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent143
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent143_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent178
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent178_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent54
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent54_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent12
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent12_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent155
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent155_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent198
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent198_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent93
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent93_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent60
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent60_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent98
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent98_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent16
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent16_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent215
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent215_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent139
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent139_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent120
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent120_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent10
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent10_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent137
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent137_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent158
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent158_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent20
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent20_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent17
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent17_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent18
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent18_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent96
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent96_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent37
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent37_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent180
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent180_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent140
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent140_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent26
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent26_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent109
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent109_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent28
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent28_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent21
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent21_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent130
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent130_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent102
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent102_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent175
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent175_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent196
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent196_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent191
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent191_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent170
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent170_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent183
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent183_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent217
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent217_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent157
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent157_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent151
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent151_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent116
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent116_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent11
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent11_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent52
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent52_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent25
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent25_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent73
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent73_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent173
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent173_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent88
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent88_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent122
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent122_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent110
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent110_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent82
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent82_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent127
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent127_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent182
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent182_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent141
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent141_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent36
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent36_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent92
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent92_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent153
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent153_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent136
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent136_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent106
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent106_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent138
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent138_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent169
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent169_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent129
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent129_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent47
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent47_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent128
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent128_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent46
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent46_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent161
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent161_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent181
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent181_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent81
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent81_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent164
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent164_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent193
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent193_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent14
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent14_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent235
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent235_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent184
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent184_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent23
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent23_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent149
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent149_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent166
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent166_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent177
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent177_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent44
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent44_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent35
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent35_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent192
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent192_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent95
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent95_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent188
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent188_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent218
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent218_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent111
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent111_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent124
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent124_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent70
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent70_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent123
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent123_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent162
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent162_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent39
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent39_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent165
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent165_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent189
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent189_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent42
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent42_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent58
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent58_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent55
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent55_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent113
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent113_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent71
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent71_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent152
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent152_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent163
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent163_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent105
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent105_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent13
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent13_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent38
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent38_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent100
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent100_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent84
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent84_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent41
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent41_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent171
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent171_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent187
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent187_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent50
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent50_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent119
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent119_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent199
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent199_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent15
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent15_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent68
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent68_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent33
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent33_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent168
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent168_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent118
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent118_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent40
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent40_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent148
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent148_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent91
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent91_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent212
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent212_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent19
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent19_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent69
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent69_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent43
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:SQLTraceEvent43_TYPE0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_object_worktable_load_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_node_database_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_global_message_delete
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_activation_task_limit_reached
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_catalog_metadata_cache_hit
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_page_compression_attempt_failed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_xml_deadlock_report
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_activation_task_aborted
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_bulk_copy_throughput
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cached_cursor_added
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_change_tracking_cleanup
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_deliverysm_event_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_filestream_file_io_trace
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_node_stolen_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_database_attached
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_object_worktable_save_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_destination_process_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cursor_worktable_use_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_partition_free_list_empty
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_object_worktable_save_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_file_read
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_sp_statement_completed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_manager_free_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_dns_lookup
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_global_message_add
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_acksm_event_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_dialog_state_change
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_timer_armed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cursor_cache_hit
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_dialog_transmission_queue_dequeue
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_error_reported
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_logreader_process_filestream_info
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_transport_stream_update
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_database_transaction_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_plan_cache_cache_hit
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_sp_statement_starting
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_node_page_life_expectancy
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_latch_acquired
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_process_boxcar
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_task_idempotent_invoke_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_manager_database_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_rpc_completed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_flush_file_buffers
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_rpc_starting
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_lazyflusher_remove
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_host_task_ring_buffer_recorded
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_latch_demoted
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_database_detached
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_file_write_completed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_acksm_event_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_file_written
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_latch_suspend_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_deadlock_monitor_state_transition
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_deadlock_monitor_perf_stats
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_deliverysm_event_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cached_cursor_removed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_filestream_file_io_dump
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_manager_target_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_plan_cache_cache_attempt
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_data_file_size_changed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_log_flush_wait
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_manager_total_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_constant_page_corruption_detected
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_logreader_add_tran_info
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_acksm_action_fire
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_errorlog_written
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_winsock_read
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_delimit_message
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_log_shrink
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_flow_control
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_module_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_message_add
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_sort_add_run_tracing
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_pool_ring_buffer_recorded
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_reclassification_phase_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_logreader_process_text_info
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_node_free_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_shrink_data_movement
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_bulk_copy_rows
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_dialog_transmission_queue_enqueue
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_destination_unsubscribe
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cursor_memory_usage
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_sql_statement_completed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:sql_statement_completed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_checkpoint_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_message_delete
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_action_fire
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cursor_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_incoming_connect_attempt
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cdc_error
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_send
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_receive_io_complete
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_deadlock_monitor_pmo_status
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_dialog_register
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_failed_hresult
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_destination_subscribe
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_task_idempotent_invoke_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_lazyflusher_submit
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_partition_free_list_requests
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_backup_restore_throughput
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_activation_stored_procedure_invoked
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_manager_stolen_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_log_flush
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_event_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_deprecation_announcement
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_page_split
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_destination_process_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_trace_flag_changed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cursor_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_deprecation_final_support
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_destination_connect
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_service_reclassify
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cursor_worktable_use_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_allocation_ring_buffer_recorded
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_log_growth
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_sort_state_change_tracing
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_sec_ekm_provider_called
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_winsock_connect_fail
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_read_complete
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_physical_page_read
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_user_settable
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_partition_free_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_service_create
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_lock_acquired
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_service_send
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_timer_set
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_reclassification_phase_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_latch_suspend_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_outgoing_connect_attempt
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_prefetch_extent
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_database_stopped
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_sql_statement_starting
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:sql_statement_starting
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_sort_statistics_tracing
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_object_delete_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_catalog_metadata_cache_entry_unpinned
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_log_cache_read
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_lock_released
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cursor_cache_attempt
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_deadlock_monitor_mem_stats
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_destination_event_fire
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_logreader_add_eor
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_filestream_file_io_request
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_filestream_file_io_failure
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_deadlock_monitor_serialized_local_wait_for_graph
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_manager_page_life_expectancy
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_leaf_page_disfavored
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cdc_session
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_close
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_process_receive_control_bl
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_app_domain_ring_buffer_recorded
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_latch_released
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_locks_lock_timeouts
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_node_total_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_file_read_completed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_catalog_metadata_cache_entry_pinned
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_task_idempotent_submit
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_lazyflusher_processing_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_checkpoint_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_trace_print
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_sort_memory_grant_adjustment
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_failed_hresult_msg
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_timer_fire
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_dialog_reclassify
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_catalog_metadata_cache_entry_added
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_object_get
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_logreader_process_text_ptr
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_page_compression_tracing
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_physical_page_write
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transport_connection_winsock_connect_success
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmitter_destination_process_sender_process
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_log_file_size_changed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_locks_lock_waits
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_buffer_node_target_pages
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_long_io_detected
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_log_file_used_size_changed
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_logreader_apply_filter_proc
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_databases_log_truncation
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cursor_plan_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_transmission_object_delete_end
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_cursor_manager_cursor_plan_begin
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\WMI:XeSqlPkg_broker_activation_task_started
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\Microsoft\SqlServer\ServerEvents\MSSQLSERVER2008:TRC_TSQL
\RAHMAN-PC-NEW\ROOT\Microsoft\SqlServer\ServerEvents\MSSQLSERVER2008:SQL_STMTRECOMPILE

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify under which `Namespace` does this `class viz Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLMSSQLSERVER2008_MSSQLMSSQLSERVER2008Databases` exist and then run code like `gwmi -Namespace "ROOT\<Path>" -Query "SELECT Name FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLMSSQLSERVER2008_MSSQLMSSQLSERVER2008Databases"`
You can use WMI Explorer to browse through namespaces and classes. WMI Explorer can be downloaded from https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wmie

Comment: Hi, before posting this question, I already played with Wmi explorer but no success. I thought maybe someone knows. Is there any Microsoft documentation around this to help?

Comment: @user1829319 From where did you come to know about this class?

Comment: Hi, as mentioned it's generated automatically by Servicenow during discovery. I have a feeling this is not correct. I want how to fix this to get sql database names using Wmi.

Comment: Try below cmdlet to see if there's mentioned class in WMI:
`Get-WMIObject –List –namespace "root" –class "*MSSQLMSSQLSERVER2008*" -Recurse | select Path`.

Comment: Hi thanks, that class doesn't return anything. I know that that class is messing. I possibly need to install something? Added all the classes for the *SQL* in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this issue:

- Repair WMI: winmgmt /salvagerepository
- Repair SQL Server 2008 (Re-install)

After this my query started working. The reset and repair installed all the required classes needed.